# How to do a vector of dates in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, vector

I need to create a vector of dates from *2018-01-01* to *2020-01-01*, the vector can **not** be continuous (eg 2018-01-01, 2018-01-02, 2018-01-03 ...), dates need not be symmetrical and include the head and the tail.

The closest I got was:

```
import pandas as pd
date_list = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2020-01-11', freq = '3M', closed= 'left')
date_list
Out[3]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-31', '2018-04-30', '2018-07-31', '2018-10-31',
           '2019-01-31', '2019-04-30', '2019-07-31', '2019-10-31'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='3M')
```

However, it does not include the head (2018-01-01) or the tail (2020-01-01).

Comment: You are almost there, use MS (month start) instead of M and no closed parameter, date_list = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2020-01-01', freq = '3MS')

Comment: `freq = '3MS'`.

Comment: Ok, but in the case ''end='2020-01-11' ?

Comment: Then the problem is with freq parameter. What would be the expected output if end = '2020-01-11' ?